# Is BiCMOS still a popular technology?

Tags: analog, manufacturing-process

A Google search has not yielded much fruit when it comes to this question, but I'm wondering if BiCMOS is still a reasonably popular technology (relative, of course, to any other non-CMOS technology). Most of what I have read seems to come from the 90s, so I'm not sure if that points to BiCMOS no longer being used as CMOS improves so much that the old benefits of BiCMOS no longer accrue to justify its use over (advanced) CMOS.

Comment: Still used in very few applications, [says Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BiCMOS).

Comment: Used in specialized cameras, https://www.tudelft.nl/en/innovatie-impact/innovation-projects/terahertz-silicon-camera, SiGe HF transistors, https://ams-osram.com/technology/full-service-foundry/technology-portfolio and sub-THz comms, https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-022-07902-0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BiCMOS still finds uses in many analog/RF commercial applications, where CMOS scaling has not resulted in improved performance (designing analog blocks in bulk CMOS <28nm is quite difficult/not cost-effective). Many high-speed optical communication receivers and transmitters are based on BiCMOS technology. RF and mmWave front-end modules are also still using BiCMOS technology, especially in PA blocks where the higher breakdown voltages associated with BiCMOS technology allow for superior reliability and output power than CMOS counterparts.